# How to read the value of attribute in XML using XPATH in a PL/SQL procedure ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, xslt, plsql

I have an xml like the following:

```
<!-- XML-Code -->
indoc := '
<Students>
     <Student Enrolled = "true">
           <SID>12456</SID>
    </Student>
    <Student Enrolled = "false">
           <SID>12345</SID>
    </Student>
</Students>';
<!-- XML Code -->
indomdoc := dbms_xmldom.newDomDocument(indoc);
```

I am using

```
dbms_xslprocessor.selectNodes(dbms_xmldom.makeNode(indomdoc),
                                        '//Student[@Enrolled="True"]');
```

This is returning me the values Of Students with attribute Enrolled as true.

and again I am using

```
dbms_xslprocessor.selectNodes(dbms_xmldom.makeNode(indomdoc),
                                        '//Student[@Enrolled="False"]');
```

to get all students who are not enrolled yet.

But I want to know is there any way to find the value of enrolled attribute using xsl processor, rather than directly giving like `@Enrolled="True"` and `@Enrolled="False"`.

Comment: From the comments in [@Alex Nikolaenkov's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009439/how-to-read-the-value-of-attribute-in-xml-using-xpath-in-a-pl-sql-procedure-oracl/5009537#5009537) this question is not clear...

Comment: My bad, I filled in the edit reason wrongly. [Please read the FAQ concerning signatures and taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 0):

XPath expression `//Student/@Enrolled` will give you all the values of the `Enrolled` attribute.

Comment: I need to get all the students who are enrolled, How can I get that value? What i mean to say is How can I compare the value returned by the expression you said with the value "true"

Comment: @Sameer, you are working with XSLT 1.0 and the only way you to do it is probably the way you do it. There are XMLSchema datatypes such as `xs:boolean` which could help you to interpret the values if the document's schema is provided but I've never used XMLSchema with XSLT. The simpliest way I know is yours or changing the semantics of the `@Enrolled` attribute in case you have control over your XML. If presence of the attribute means that student is enrolled then you can use `//Student[@Enrolled]` and `Student[not(@Enrolled)]` which is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an XPath expression referencing the attribute value?

```
fn:data(//Student/@Enrolled)
```

Am I missing some part of your problem?

Comment: My bad, I filled in the edit reason wrongly. [Please read the FAQ concerning signatures and taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).